# Where's the error in my .htaccess RewriteRule Regexp?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this url

```
http://www.test.racebooking.net/rankings/classifica.html
```

to point to

```
http://www.test.racebooking.net/rankings.php
```

thus, i wrote this rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^rankings\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.html$ /rankings.php
```

I really can't figure out why, when i type the first url, i get a 404 error msg.

1. RewriteEngine is on.
2. /rankings.php exists.
3. Moreover, I have another RewriteRule, much more complex, which i
   wrote, which is working like charm.
4. classifica.html doesn't exist. I'm just updating my website with
   more SEO friendly urls

What's wrong with my rule??

When i test the regexp in any online regexp tester it detects the string "rankings/classifica.html", this means the regexp actually corresponds, but nothing is working....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the regex, thats for sure. There is something else thats going wrong with your code.

Comment: The ordering of RewriteRules is often important. Just saying you have anotherone that's working, doesn't mean there isn't interference.

Comment: I'm really going out of mind...if that can help, here is my .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/xyRuDmv5 . The rule at line 10 works perfectly, the rule at line 8 (the one i pasted here) nope.

Comment: Your rules work for me. You may have error in /rankings.php . Can you simplify it and rerun the test?

Comment: It is the same problem due to `MultiViews` see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20302544/548225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, but i didn't find out why it happens.

Basically, if *pattern* and *substitution* start with the same word, the RewriteRule doesn't work.

**EXAMPLE**

If i write this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^rankings\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.html$ /rankings.php
```

and type this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.net/rankings/classifica.html
```

I get a 404 Error. Even if the Regexp is correct, the apache RewriteEngine is not working. Instead, if i write this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ran-kings\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.html$ /rankings.php
```

and type this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.net/ran-kings/classifica.html
```

Everything works fine.