# In RewriteRule if pattern and substitution begin with the same string, the RewriteRule doesn't work. Why?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In this post: [**My previous post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274123/wheres-the-error-in-my-htaccess-rewriterule-regexp) i was asking help for a strange issue: a correct regexp was not working in a RewriteRule. After hours of work i found how to fix the error and i found out this strange thing.

If i write this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^rankings\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.html$ /rankings.php
```

and type this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.net/rankings/classifica.html
```

I get a 404 Error. Even if the Regexp is correct, the apache RewriteEngine is not working.
Instead, if i write this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ran-kings\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.html$ /rankings.php
```

and type this URL

```
http://www.mywebsite.net/ran-kings/classifica.html
```

Everything works fine. I made many other tests with different rules and pages and i always got the same problem.
The conclusion i came to is that if the pattern and substitution begin with the same word, the RewriteRule doesn't work.

How come is this possible? Anybody knows why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually real problem is the [**`MultiViews` option**](http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews). `Multiviews` allow substitutions of file extensions, so you can call an URL like `http://www.example.com/page.php` using `http://www.example.com/page`.

**Use this line on top of your .htaccess to disable it:**

```
Options -MultiViews
```